# UIContainerView embed don't work sometimes

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uicontainerview

I'm facing a wierd issue. I'm pushing UIViewcontroller into UINavigationcontroller. This viewcontroller have container view which embeds a collection view. Everything is set up in storyboard.

Sometimes after build & run this embedded segue doesn't happen, viewcontroller is pushed into navigation, but collection view is not embedded. To fix this I have to change something in this storyboard, save it, revert it and save it again. Sometimes I have to repeat these steps few times, before it starts working.

Main problem is, that in most cases it works in debug mode, but when I make release build, then stops working. After some changes and reverts I got it to work in release build.

Clean is not helping. This was happening in XCode7 and now also in XCode8.\

I have few more container views in app, but they are all working ok.

Comment: version controll doesn't show any changes on source, after I manage it to work.

Comment: I've replaced containerview with navigation controller, and set collection view as rootViewControllert. This way works perfect.